# Compensation in case of delay from the EU via Turkish Airlines

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, eu, turkish-airlines

I am traveling from an EU country through Istanbul, all via Turkish Airlines. My connection time at the Istanbul airport is for less than 90 minutes. In the unfortunate case that I miss my connection, I know that I am entitled to compensation because of the EC 261 regulation. However, I am unclear on a few issues.

1. Can I only claim the compensation or do I also get assistance at the airport (i.e., rebooking, food, accommodation)?
2. What is the best way to claim the compensation? Can I apply at the airport or do I have to do it online?

I know that I have to meet a few criteria to claim the compensation, i.e., the delay has to be longer than 3 hours, the distance of your delay, etc.

Comment: From what EU airport will you depart?

Comment: From Frankfurt, Germany.

Comment: Turkish Airlines passenger rights answers some of this question https://cdn.turkishairlines.com/m/3ab07cf4b870382e/original/FR-67-0329-Yolcu-haklar-Brosuru-ENG-copy.PDF

Answer (score 1):

What determines the financial compensation eligibility under EC261/2004 is the arrival (time) at the *final* destination as specified on your ticket. Any such financial compensation does NOT release the airline from its obligations (to transport you to your final destination), i.e. the airline must still rebook you onto the next available flight and provide refreshments/accommodation if *applicable*. You should go to the airline's support desk at the airport to get rebooked/food/accommodation. For TK in Instanbul you could ask for a free access/entry into one of the TK lounges (which feature plenty of food and place to rest).

The best way to claim the financial compensation under EC261/2004 is to contact the airline directly. Each airline (operating flights from EU airports) should have a section on the website dedicated to claims under EC261/2004 (or at least provide details how to make such a claim).

Have a look at the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Compensation_Regulation) for a very decent summary of your rights